# How to check efficient whether a recordset value isnull before passing it to a called function?

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, recordset, is-empty

I have a sub which creates a recordset. A function is called with values from the recordset. The goal is to use multiple values from the recordset, however, there is a possibility that a recordset value is null, then the function call will result in an error: "Invalid use of Null". To handle this error, each time the recordset value is checked for null values, if it is null, it will be replaced with an empty string. However, the way I have programmed this feels very inefficient, even more when later on more than ten parameters should be checked. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

I have skipped the last part off the code as this is not necessary to understand my question. I've replaced it with ......... If needed, I will edit and provide full code.

```
Sub CallFunctionWithArray()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim arrValues(1 To 3) As Variant

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & CurrentProject.Path & "\Northwind.mdb"

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM CustomersCopy", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
    rst.MoveFirst        
    Do Until rst.EOF = True

    If IsNull(rst![CompanyName]) Then
        arrValues(1) = ""
    Else
        arrValues(1) = rst![CompanyName]
    End If

    If IsNull(rst![DateTest]) Then
        arrValues(2) = ""
    Else
        arrValues(2) = rst![DateTest]
    End If

    If IsNull(rst![INTTest]) Then
        arrValues(3) = ""
    Else
        arrValues(3) = rst![INTTest]
    End If

        Call ReturnValuesOfArray(arrValues(1), arrValues(2), arrValues(3))    
.........
End Sub

Function ReturnValuesOfArray(ByVal ValueOne As String, ByVal ValueTwo As String, ByVal ValueThree As String)
    Debug.Print "Waarde variabele 1: " & ValueOne
    Debug.Print "Waarde variabele 2: " & ValueTwo
    Debug.Print "Waarde variabele 3: " & ValueThree
End Function
```

There is no problem with the code, it does what it's supposed to do. However, I will be passing many more parameters to the function when this is going to be really used.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through the fields of your Recordset instead of hard coding for every field.  Using your code as a starting point, it could look something like this:

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim i As Integer

   If Not (rst.EOF And rst.BOF) Then
      rst.MoveFirst

      Do Until rst.EOF = True
         For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
            If IsNull(rst.Fields(i).Value) Then
               arrValues(i) = ""
            Else
               arrValues(i) = rst.Fields(i).Value
            End If
         Next
      Loop
   End If
End Sub
```

Incorporating the ideas presented by @HansUp and @Mathieu Guindon, the code is even shorter:

```
Private Sub Test()
   Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim i As Integer

   Do Until rst.EOF
      For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
         arrValues(i + 1) = Nz(rst.Fields(i).Value, "")
      Next
   Loop
End Sub
```

The rest of your code can be simplified, too, while allowing for any number of parameters:

```
Function ReturnValuesOfArray(ByVal Values As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = LBound(Values) To UBound(Values)
       Debug.Print "Waarde variabele " & i & ": " & Values(i)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Pretty sure `rst.BOF` check is useless if you removed the would-be redundant `rst.MoveFirst` - what would be a reason for a brand new recordset to *not* be on its first record before you start iterating it? Also `rst.EOF = True` is redundant, `rst.EOF` is already a `Boolean`, so `Do Until rst.EOF` is all you need.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I agree with your points, I just modified the OP's code with the changes.  I suppose I could have made it more efficient, too.

Comment: The array is one-based and the `Fields` collection is zero-based.  So to avoid an off-by-one-error they can do `arrValues(i +1) = Nz(rst.Fields(i).Value, "")`

Comment: @HansUp or simply use `For Each` to iterate the fields - object collections are (much) more efficiently iterated with a `For Each` loop anyway. (and use a `Dictionary` keyed with field names instead of an array)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Or do the Null substitution with query field expressions (instead of `SELECT *`).  Then the VBA could be simpler still.

Comment: Definitely. `SELECT *` is arguably a source of potential headaches in itself.

Comment: @Sunfile If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The [Nz Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) does what I think you want.

```vb
arrValues(1) = Nz(rst![CompanyName], "")
arrValues(2) = Nz(rst![DateTest], "")
arrValues(3) = Nz(rst![INTTest], "")
```